# Can't get mlb stats data from sportsreference.com

Tags: python, html, web-scraping, scrapy

When I enter the command below in the terminal

```
scrapy shell "https://www.baseball-reference.com/teams/BOS/2023.shtml"
```

I have no problem getting any of the data & I can find everything on the page. But when I scrape for it (via scrapy crawl mlb_players) I get no data. I see the following in the terminal

```
2023-08-17 15:26:03 [scrapy.core.engine] DEBUG: Crawled (200) <GET https://www.baseball-reference.com/teams/BOS/2023.shtml> (referer: None)
```

I don't know why I'm having these issue/s. The code I use for the stats table is

```
for stats in response.xpath('//table[@id="team_batting"]/tbody/tr'):
```

but scrapy doesn't find the table or any of the divs (all_team_batting/div_team_batting) that contain the table. The only data I'm still able to get from the page is the year & team using the code below

```
item_team = response.xpath('//h1/span[2]/text()').get()
item_year = response.xpath('//h1/span[1]/text()').get()
```

I don't know what's going on? I had no problems before... all feedback and/or input is welcome. Don't know what changed...

Comment: What version of scrapy are you using? I could successfully get the table (55 entries for your xpath query) ... Maybe this is a dynamic content that, sometimes, returns empty? Maybe they use your source IP or any other info to determine which data is sent back to you?

Comment: Thanks for reply @LeandroRodriguesdeSouza & when I run scrapy version at the terminal it says Scrapy 2.4.1. Also I've always had scrapy useragent installed so (as far as I can tell) I'm scraping with proxies & have a 5sec delay between requests. I really try to abide by their rules/be a good guy & not block site access with too many requests. Hope my source IP isnt an issue the response is 200 so indicates everything is OK???

Comment: great @Alexander do you have any code (did you use the xpath or css) & what version of scrapy are you using? didnt think about version until previous comment

Comment: I used the same code you provided in your question and it worked fine